# @Autowired not working in multi-module application

Tags: java, spring, autowired, multi-module, spring-repositories

I need to @Autowire database services or repositores form "database" module in "game" module.
Already added those annotations in main "Application" class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.rydzwr.tictactoe")
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.rydzwr.tictactoe")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.rydzwr.tictactoe")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Adding them in constructor is much more difficult, becouse I'm need to create list of instances of those classes in StrategySelector:

```
@Service
public class GameStrategySelector {
    private final List<BuildGameStrategy> strategyList = asList(
           new LocalPlayerGameStrategy(),
            new MultiPlayerGameStrategy()
    );

    public BuildGameStrategy chooseStrategy(GameDto gameDto) {
        return strategyList
                .stream()
                .filter(strategy -> strategy.applies(gameDto))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(new ErrorGameTypeStrategy());
    }
}
```

Or, maybe someone has better idea, for StrategySelector logic?

Here is class with given problem:

```
@Component
public class LocalPlayerGameStrategy implements BuildGameStrategy {
    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void buildGame(GameDto gameDto) {
        Game game = new GameBuilder(gameDto.getGameSize(), gameDto.getGameDifficulty()).build();
        gameService.save(game);

        User caller = userService.findByName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        assert caller != null;

        for (PlayerDto playerDto : gameDto.getPlayers()) {
            Player player = new PlayerBuilder().setGame(game).setUser(caller).setPlayerDetails(playerDto).build();
            playerService.save(player);
        }

        game.setState(GameState.IN_PROGRESS);

        gameService.save(game);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean applies(GameDto gameDto) {
        return gameDto.getPlayers().stream().allMatch(p -> p.getPlayerType().equals(PlayerType.LOCAL.name()));
    }
}
```

I tried to autowire repositores and services with implemented logic as well.
Every time all of them:

```
@Autowired
    private GameService gameService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;
```

ARE NULL

I tried everything I found on google

Comment: If those services are null, they might not be in your component scanning. Have you specified the path to those services in your component scan correctly?

Comment: All of my modules are in "com.rydzwr.tictactoe".
Repositories/services are in "com.rydzwr.tictactoe.database" and I need them in "com.rydzwr.tictactoe.game"

Comment: Even if I'm trying to @Autowire repositoryAdapter, implemented in same module with repository in constructor, still can't

Comment: Have you implemented the GameService、UserService &  PlayerService  class, in rigth package?Sometimes, copying other codes will ignore the correctness of the package path.Also, your service needs to be managed by spring (plus @service or @Component). 
Because you only give a partial code, you can't guess the reason in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can't create `new` instances of `LocalPlayerGameStrategy` and `MultiPlayerGameStrategy` inside `GameStrategySelector` they won't be spring beans so they can't @Autowire other beans.

Modify your `GameStrategySelector` to inject all `BuildGameStrategy` instead of creating them manually

```
@Service
public class GameStrategySelector {
    private final List<BuildGameStrategy> strategyList;
    
    public GameStrategySelector(List<BuildGameStrategy> allStrategies){
        strategyList = allStrategies;
    }

    public BuildGameStrategy chooseStrategy(GameDto gameDto) {
        return strategyList
                .stream()
                .filter(strategy -> strategy.applies(gameDto))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(new ErrorGameTypeStrategy());
    }
}
```

Comment: Injected Worked